# How to set and group pandas multi-level columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that has the shape like this:

```
   PX_LAST PX_OPEN PX_CLOSE ticker source timestamp
0        1       2        3      A   LSE   20180101
1        4       5        6      A   LSE   20180102
1        7       8        9      B   LSE   20180101
1       10      11       12      B   LSE   20180102
....
```

I want to massage it to the following format:

```
                                     A                          B
                                   LSE                        LSE
            PX_LAST, PX_CLOSE, PX_OPEN PX_LAST, PX_CLOSE, PX_OPEN
timestamp 
20180101          1         2       3        7         8        9 
20180102          4         5       6       10        11       12
....
```

I tried to first use `set_index` to set the ticker and source columns to the row index and use `unstack` to push them on to the column axis which does seem to work

```
df.set_index(['timestamp', 'ticker', 'source'])
    .unstack(level=[1,2])
    .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
    .swaplevel(1,2,axis=1)
```

This does the trick, but has two problems: 1) it is very verbose, with all the swaplevel call we need to do to get the columns into the right shape. 2) It seems it does not do the grouping I wish it does, i.e the result I get is like this:

```
              LSE     LSE      LSE      LSE ...
          PX_LAST PX_LAST PX_CLOSE PX_CLOSE ...
timestamp 
20180101       1        7        2       8  ...
20180102       4        8        5      11  ...
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this so I can get the format I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `melt`, `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
u = df.melt(['ticker', 'source', 'timestamp'])
(u.set_index(u.columns.difference({'value'}).tolist())['value']
  .unstack([1, 0, -1])
  .sort_index(axis=1))

ticker           A                        B                
source         LSE                      LSE                
variable  PX_CLOSE PX_LAST PX_OPEN PX_CLOSE PX_LAST PX_OPEN
timestamp                                                  
20180101         3       1       2        9       7       8
20180102         6       4       5       12      10      11
```

---

Or `melt`, and `pivot_table`:

```
u = df.melt(['ticker', 'source', 'timestamp'])
u.pivot_table(index='timestamp', 
              columns=['ticker','source','variable'], 
              values='value')

ticker           A                        B                
source         LSE                      LSE                
variable  PX_CLOSE PX_LAST PX_OPEN PX_CLOSE PX_LAST PX_OPEN
timestamp                                                  
20180101         3       1       2        9       7       8
20180102         6       4       5       12      10      11
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should be a bit changed - with order of columns in `set_index`, omit second `swaplevel` and added [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['timestamp', 'source', 'ticker'])
        .unstack(level=[1,2])
        .swaplevel(0,2,axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1)
)
print (df)
ticker           A                        B                
source         LSE                      LSE                
          PX_CLOSE PX_LAST PX_OPEN PX_CLOSE PX_LAST PX_OPEN
timestamp                                                  
20180101         3       1       2        9       7       8
20180102         6       4       5       12      10      11
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposition is to change your solution the following way:

Step 1: `df.set_index(['timestamp', 'ticker', 'source']).unstack([1, 2])`,
just as you did.

It leaves columns in the following shape:

```
          PX_LAST     PX_OPEN     PX_CLOSE
ticker          A   B       A   B        A   B
source        LSE LSE     LSE LSE      LSE LSE
```

(and `timestamp` as the index).

Step 2: `reorder_levels([1, 2, 0], axis=1)`, instead of your 2
`swaplevel` instructions.

It leaves columns as:

```
ticker          A       B       A       B        A        B
source        LSE     LSE     LSE     LSE      LSE      LSE
          PX_LAST PX_LAST PX_OPEN PX_OPEN PX_CLOSE PX_CLOSE
```

And the last step is `sort_index(axis=1, level=[0,1], sort_remaining=False)`

Note that you sort **only** level 0 and 1, so the order in the last level
remains unchanged (PX_LAST, PX_OPEN, PX_CLOSE).

So the whole script (i.e. a single instruction) is:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['timestamp', 'ticker', 'source']).unstack([1, 2])\
    .reorder_levels([1, 2, 0], axis=1)\
    .sort_index(axis=1, level=[0,1], sort_remaining=False)
```

When you print the result, you will get:

```
ticker          A                        B
source        LSE                      LSE
          PX_LAST PX_OPEN PX_CLOSE PX_LAST PX_OPEN PX_CLOSE
timestamp
20180101        1       2        3       7       8        9
20180102        4       5        6      10      11       12
```